# How to add data from one dataframe to another using Pandas transpose?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Objective:** to fill in one dataframe with another using transpose

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Attributes': ['love', 'family','tech']})
df.T
```

Produces this output:

```
               0         1     2
Attributes  love    family  tech
```

Secondarily, I have another dataframe that is empty:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Attribute_01',
                'Attribute_02',
                'Attribute_03']
```

I would like to bring the two dataframes together to produce the following:

```
Attribute_01  Attribute_02  Attribute_03
love          family        tech
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df
  Attributes
0       love
1     family
2       tech
```

**Option 1**
`rename`

```
df.T.rename(dict(enumerate(data.columns)), axis=1)

           Attribute_01 Attribute_02 Attribute_03
Attributes         love       family         tech
```

---

**Option 2**
`set_index`

```
df.set_index(data.columns).T

           Attribute_01 Attribute_02 Attribute_03
Attributes         love       family         tech
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to change the column name in df1

```
df.columns=data.columns
df
Out[741]: 
           Attribute_01 Attribute_02 Attribute_03
Attributes         love       family         tech
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.loc` accessor to set the first row of `data` using a listified `df['Attributes']`.

```
data.loc[0] = df['Attributes'].tolist()
```

Result:

```
  Attribute_01 Attribute_02 Attribute_03
0         love       family         tech
```